# Get the element that follows another element in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, text

I have an html that comes from an analysis with BeautifulSoup and I would like to extract the following `star0` : `sa2`.

```
>>>short_comment[1]['name']

<div class="author">
   <a href="/member/?id=59465221" target="_blank">唐牛</a>
   　<span class="star0 sa2"></span></div>
```

I tried one thing [with regex:](https://regex101.com/r/eCJd1b/2) `star0\s[a-zA-Z0-9]` but nothing came back. Now I am trying replacing by `<` and separate the string on this last one:

```
>>> s = s.replace('<','>')
>>> s.split('>')
['', 'div class="author"', ' ', 'a href="/member/?id=59465221" target="_blank"', '唐牛', '/a', ' ', 'span class="star0 sa2"', '', '/span', '', '/div', '']
>>> s.find("star0")
```

I also tried with BS4 to get the class out of the element that would have matched with the class "author"

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0'}
base_url = 'https://www.nosetime.com'

def get_perfume_as_dict(url):
  print(base_url + url)
  response_unicode = requests.get(base_url + url, headers=headers)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(response_unicode.text, 'html.parser')
  perfume = {}
  perfume["short_comment"] = [
                              {"name": name.text,
                               "rating": name.span['class'][1],
                               "comment": comment.text} for 
                              name,
                              comment in zip(
                                  soup.find_all('div', {'class':"author"}), 
                                  soup.find_all('div', {'class':"hfshow1"}), 
                                  )
                              ] #soup.find('li', {'id':'itemcomment'}) # soup.find_all('span ', {'class':'fav_cnt'})
```

But it seems to be stuck in a loop when I launch it:

```
get_perfume_as_dict("/xiangshui/350870-oulong-atelier-cologne-oolang-infini.html")
```

Comment: `BeautifulSoup` would let you extract your `class` attribute of `div class="author"`

Answer (score 0):

Use `BeautifulSoup` to query your html

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

short_comment = """<div class="author">
   <a href="/member/?id=59465221" target="_blank">唐牛</a>
   　<span class="star0 sa2"></span></div>"""
   
soup = BeautifulSoup(short_comment, "html.parser")
print(soup.find("div", {'class':'author'}).span['class'])
```

**Output:**

```
['star0', 'sa2']
```

Comment: I admit it works there but I tried to implement it in a function that goes scratch the original webpage and it seems to be stuck in a loop ...